# How do I remove subtitles from vlckit?

Tags: libvlc

I've written an app in swift that uses the vlckit framework.  I have managed to get subtitles working by using

```swift
let url = URL(string: "file://Users/lonespeaker/test-subitltle.srt")
mediaPlayer.addPlaybackSlave(url, type: .subtitle, enforce: true)
```

but if the user wants to disable the subtitles after selecting one, I am stuck.

I have tried the following but had no luck

```swift
let url = URL(string: "")
mediaPlayer.addPlaybackSlave(url, type: .subtitle, enforce: true)
```

I've googled for an answer to remove the PlaybackSlave but there doesn't seem to be an API for it.

Here is an extract of my code :

```swift
guard let url = URL(string: "file://Users/lonespeaker/test-file.mkv") else { return }
let media = VLCMedia(url: url)
mediaPlayer.media = media

mediaPlayer.delegate = self
mediaPlayer.drawable = self.movieView

mediaPlayer.play()
```

then in the IBAction for disabling subtitles

```swift
@IBAction func disableSubtitles(_ sender: Any) {
    let url = URL(string: "")
    mediaPlayer.addPlaybackSlave(url, type: .subtitle, enforce: true)
}
```

I would have expected the PlaybackSlave to be changed/overwritten by the new URL and therefore disabling subtitles.

I would also expect an API call to disable a Playback Slave, but there doesn't appear to be one.

Anyone help?  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is too complex. You can add an infinite number of playback slaves which indeed cannot be cleared using VLCKit at this point.

However, VLC will expose a list of available subtitles tracks during playback regardless of their source (you cannot differentiate between subtitles internal to the video and those added through an input slave), which you can iterate on and display to the user. Additionally, there is the player option to set the subtitles track ID you want to show. Those IDs can be queried from the API, too (note that the IDs can be 0, 1, 2, ... but it is perfectly legal to be 201, 4022, 8444, ..., too). However, to just disable, set this option to -1.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It works perfectly using             mediaPlayer.currentVideoSubTitleIndex = -1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not exposed by vlckit, but libvlc does offer [`libvlc_media_slaves_clear`](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media.html#ga0866791713e030d8c3028fc09cd2fa18).

You should try adding support for it in a local vlckit fork, and if it works, open a pull request. Other people might be interested.